# Scripture references - from memory or "search engine"?

Tags: discussion, answers

Essentially, when responding to a question with reference to the scriptures, I tend to base it on memory, then use Google to find a reference source. However, in the interest of providing as reliable sources as possible, I wonder if there are "search engine(s)" or other sources that people generally search, to refer to in answers.

Main sources used by answers on the site seems to be:

- [Access to Insight](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism)

What do you use as a reference source? Your own memory, from having studied the scripture, or do you look it up in a search engine?

(Wasn't sure if this was a question for the main site, regarding what sources are online, and another for this Meta, regarding accuracy of sources/quotes, please suggest revisions for clarification)

*(On a side note, I am working with a monastery to build a cross-reference database for teachings - multimedia files - and am looking for reliable sources with taxonomies and synonyms that can be referenced from there as well)*

Comment: You should talk to Alex Genaud (You're not him, are you?)

Comment: @tuttadhammo Thank you - no I am not. I contacted you via Linkedin regarding Alex. I appreciate the suggestion. _/\\_

Answer (score 5):

In the answers I give, I rely on memory first and then complement it with bookmarked pages & Google searches. I also make use of [Yuttadhammo](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/18/yuttadhammo)'s excellent [Digital Pali Reader](http://pali.sirimangalo.org/).

Since you didn't mention, [SuttaCentral](http://suttacentral.net/) is a growing comprehensive resource for references and might help you with your cross-reference database. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I to go off memory and that usually allows me to find what I'm looking for on accesstoinsight, which has always been my go to. Sometimes though I have to go to google if I know what I'm looking for but might not be phrasing it right.